# How to set API subscription key for Bing autocomplete?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

The following code shows:
Invalid Bing Search API subscription key!
Please paste yours into the source code.

I found I need to replace "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY" with my access key, how do I get my access key for a C# Windows Forms Application, and publish it for everyone?

This is the program, I need to get autocomplete of Bing search.
https://sites.google.com/site/searchfromdesktop/

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BingSearchApisQuickstart
{
class Program
{
    // Replace the accessKey string value with your valid access key.
    const string accessKey = "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY";

    const string uriBase = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search"; 

    const string searchTerm = "Yosemite National Park"; //Replace with your search terms.


    // Used to return search results including relevant headers
    struct SearchResult
    {
        public String jsonResult;
        public Dictionary<String, String> relevantHeaders;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        if (accessKey.Length == 32)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Searching the Web for: " + searchTerm);

            SearchResult result = BingWebSearch(searchTerm);

            Console.WriteLine("\nRelevant HTTP Headers:\n");
            foreach (var header in result.relevantHeaders)
                Console.WriteLine(header.Key + ": " + header.Value);

            Console.WriteLine("\nJSON Response:\n");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonPrettyPrint(result.jsonResult));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Bing Search API subscription key!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please paste yours into the source code.");
        }

        Console.Write("\nPress Enter to exit ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a Bing Web search and return the results as a SearchResult.
    /// </summary>
    static SearchResult BingWebSearch(string searchQuery)
    {
        // Construct the URI of the search request
        var uriQuery = uriBase + "?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(searchQuery);

        // Perform the Web request and get the response
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriQuery);
        request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = accessKey;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
        string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        // Create result object for return
        var searchResult = new SearchResult()
        {
            jsonResult = json,
            relevantHeaders = new Dictionary<String, String>()
        };

        // Extract Bing HTTP headers
        foreach (String header in response.Headers)
        {
            if (header.StartsWith("BingAPIs-") || header.StartsWith("X-MSEdge-"))
                searchResult.relevantHeaders[header] = response.Headers[header];
        }

        return searchResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Formats the given JSON string by adding line breaks and indents.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="json">The raw JSON string to format.</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted JSON string.</returns>
    static string JsonPrettyPrint(string json)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            return string.Empty;

        json = json.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("\t", "");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool quote = false;
        bool ignore = false;
        char last = ' ';
        int offset = 0;
        int indentLength = 2;

        foreach (char ch in json)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '"':
                    if (!ignore) quote = !quote;
                    break;
                case '\\':
                    if (quote && last != '\\') ignore = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (quote)
            {
                sb.Append(ch);
                if (last == '\\' && ignore) ignore = false;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append(new string(' ', ++offset * indentLength));
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append(new string(' ', --offset * indentLength));
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append(new string(' ', offset * indentLength));
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        sb.Append(' ');
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (quote || ch != ' ') sb.Append(ch);
                        break;
                }
            }
            last = ch;
        }

        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get the access key from Microsoft. They do have a free trial, but at some point you have to pay to use it, and it's priced based on number of transactions.  Follow this link https://blogs.bing.com/search-quality-insights/2017-11/Start-exploring-Bing-Search-APIs-in-under-5-minutes which will give you all the details needed.

Comment: why do i need to pay to get autocomplete of their search? i did the one of Google for free...

Comment: Follow the link and read through their documentation. All code you have posted so far is the sample Bing API code directly from that site.  You can see through that link the way to get the Access key. If you read in their info it indicates it's a free trial through their Azure program.

Comment: What link? would you please tell me in short if I can get autocomplete and publish the program without payment? otherwise link me...

Comment: You can get a free access key from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=autosuggest-api. It will be valid for 30 days with 1K calls.

Comment: I want one only for autocomplete valid forever, how can i do that?

Comment: It's not supported for now. After 1 month or 1K calls you need to buy subscription.